# What's the right way to configure React Storybook to respect Webpack's context field for relative imports?

Tags: webpack, storybook

consider:

```
src/
|_ components
  |_ thing // import tool from 'utils' <--- not relative ('../utils'), fancy webpack context/resolve trick
|_ utils/
  |_ tool
```

webpack allows you to fake relative imports [like so](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context):

```
context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
```

This allows you to write all imports in `src/` as if they alias to `node_modules` without having to manually crawl `../../../../../.......`

Using this in my app's webpack config is easy.

When I try to use the same trick in storybook's webpack config, so that it doesn't choke on my tricky imports, I get errors like this:

```
Error in ./src/components/thing
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'utils' in 'src/components/thing'
```

Is there any good way to accomplish this?